# Understanding Adv. abbreviation at end of 1921 Arkansas newspaper notice?

Tags: united-states, 1920s, newspaper, abbreviations, arkansas

I found the following posted in a Arkansas newspaper in 1921 regarding a family member of mine:

> NOTICE--I hereby give notice that I will not be responsible for any
>   debts contracted by my wife, Stella Greenfield.  H. E. Greenfield. 
>   Adv.

What is the meaning, or significance of the **Adv.** at the end of notice?

Comment: Hi taximadman, does Adv. appear at the end of any other notices?

Comment: I didn't notice any other notices.  This one was sandwiched in between to articles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the job titles in the legal profession is [*Advocate*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=legal+advocate&oq=legal+advocate).

In some regions, the abbreviation *Adv* is suffixed to a lawyer's name to indicate this position.  Other similar expressions would be JP (Justice of the Peace).

I'm not sure of the practice of Arkansas but the use of Adv in this case suggests that the individual was a legal [Advocate](http://thelawdictionary.org/advocate/).  As the document that you quote appears to be of a legal nature, this adds weight to the idea.

Comment: So your saying H.E. Greenfield, husband of Stella Greenfield, was a lawyer?

Comment: Unless you have any reason to suspect otherwise, I would start by assuming that H.E. Greenfield's advocate placed the advertisement on his behalf (since it's a legal sort of thing being announced).